# Apply terminal colors in gui?

Tags: terminal, color

I am on neovim with Oni. vim-netranger plugin uses terminal colors in this format to highlight things. It does work in terminal with neovim , but not in a gui app.

I am looking for a way to replace this that will work.

```
def c256(msg, c, background):
    if background:
        return '[38;5;{};7m{}[0m'.format(c, msg)
    else:
        return '[38;5;{}m{}[0m'.format(c, msg)
```

This string is printed into a line(in a buffer) somehow.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are ANSI escape sequences which are commonly used to print colored text in terminal windows. If valid sequences are being inserted into Vim buffers then you'll be happy to know that there's a plugin that will translate to Vim highlighting/colors: [AnsiEsc](https://github.com/powerman/vim-plugin-AnsiEsc)

Here's are basic examples of the concepts...

---

*Using something close to one of your samples this shows what happens on shell command line...*

[image: ASCII escape sequence in Bash]

---

*Now if we redirect the printf output to a file and open with generic Vim we see...*

[image: ASCII escape sequence in Vim]

---

*With plugin installed just run command `:AnsiEsc` and you get...*

[image: demo of AnsiEsc plugin]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by text line OP means the command line window (e.g., via `echom`), use `:echohl` to set the colors and `:echom` to print strings.

Note that `echohl` uses the available highlight groups; you may want to use `execute` and `highlight`to create your own from function arguments if custom highlights are needed. Otherwise, just lean on the provided groups and trust the colorscheme.

For a buffer you need to use custom syntax commands, or borrow an existing syntax.

See the relevant docs.

Comment: Thank, but it is just a buffer. Not the command line window.

Answer (score 0):

I ask it also here

https://github.com/ipod825/vim-netranger/issues/22

and what he wrote is:

> I now see that this is because I didn't set the highlit color for gui
>   in the syntax file. The line should be modified to something like:

```
 'hi NETRhi'.c.' ctermfg='.c.' ctermbg=None guifg=#rrggbb guibg =None'
```

It is working now.