# Vim errorformat to parse output with ANSI color codes

Tags: errorformat

I try to parse output with ANSI codes and I can't cope with definition errorformat.
Example output:

```
^[[0;31;49mtestdata/examples.rb:3^[[0m Array#shuffle.first is slower than Array#sample.$
```

After parse I get:

```
|| testdata/examples.rb:3 Array#shuffle.first is slower than Array#sample.
```

In this example use ANSI code red color: ^[[0;31;49m. Character ^[ is <1b> in HEX. I tried use this character in efm:

```
"%s/<1b>%p[0;31;49m%f:%l%s/<1b>%p[0m %m"
```

but it didn't work.
Also I tried to use \033 character (^[ in octal):

```
"\033%p[0;31;49m%f:%l\033%p[0m %m"
```

And it doesn't work too.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. If you want to show colors by way of ANSI escape codes there's no native support for that but there's a plugin with this capability as noted in my answer here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20273/apply-terminal-colors-in-gui/20281#20281

Comment: @BLayer i think OP is trying to use errorformat/quickfix with a tool that produces ANSI color codes in it’s output. Best solution is to make sure that tool doesn’t produce color when it’s output isn’t to a terminal.

Comment: I'd say the best soution, then, is to use AnsiEsc (if it works with quickfix/errorformat, that is). If you expressly don't want color then hope that the relevant tool(s) have `--no-color` or equivalent.

Comment: I develop tool for a some linter. Thank you for your recommendations. I solved the problem via using linux utilit sed that remove ansi codes.

Comment: Well-design CLI tools shouldn't output colour codes when the output is not an interactive terminal, unless explicitly told to do so. I would report it in the issue's bug tracker, as this will cause problems in various tools.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Not sure if this is really a duplicate, as I believe the quickfix is a bit special with that and `'errorformat'` is odd around these ANSI color codes... +1 to what Martin said about CLI shouldn't output color codes when used this way. In any case, stripping those out might be a good idea, since Vim will most surely not display the colors according to them anyways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all I solved this problem using **sed** linux utilit. My solution:

```
some-cli | sed "s/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g" | some-errorformat-vim-tool
```

where `sed "s/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g"` remove all ansi-codes.

This answer helped my: [Can Vim interpret terminal color escape codes?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/485/can-vim-interpret-terminal-color-escape-codes)

Comment: Glad you solved your problem, but long term it's easier to have `some-cli` not generate colors when it doens't go to the terminal!